# The analytic function at infinity

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions

Prove that if $
f(z)
$
is analytic at the infinity, then:
$$
\lim_{z\to\infty}f'(z)=0
$$

Answer (score 10):

Put $g(z) = f\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)$. Then $g(z)$ is analytic in a neighborhood of $z = 0$. This means that the derivative of $g(z)$ exists at $z =0$. We have

$$g'(z) = -\frac{1}{z^2}f'\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)$$

We can write this as

$$f'\left(\frac{1}{z}\right) =-z^2 g'(z) $$

The limit for $z$ to zero is thus zero, therefore the limit of $f'(z)$ to infinity is zero.

Answer (score 3):

That's wrong. $f(z) =z$ is analytic and has 
$$ f'(z) = 1 \to 1, \qquad z \to \infty $$

Comment: $f(z) = z$ has a pole at infinity.

Comment: Yes sorry I have just edited it .its analytic at infinity .

Comment: Is there any difference ?

Comment: @user401187 Clearly $f(z) = z$ does not exist at infinity, so this function cannot be analytic there. From Liouville's theorem it follows that a function that is analytic everywhere and also at infinity, must be constant, the derivative of that is then zero. So, such cases are trivial.

Comment: The question was changed.