# Proving $\lim_{z\to \infty}f'(z)=0$

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let assume $f(z)$ is defined and analytic at $|z|>1$ and such that $\lim_{z\to \infty}f(z)=L$ when $L<\infty$
>
> Prove: $\lim_{z\to \infty}f'(z)=0$

$f(z)$ is defined and analytic at $|z|>1$ so it can be expanded to a power series $f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{a_n}{z^n}$ at $|z|>1$ now we know that $lim_{z\to \infty}f(z)=\lim_{z\to \infty}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{a_n}{z^n}=L$

Taking the derivative we get:

$\lim_{z\to \infty}f'(z)=\lim_{z\to \infty}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}-n*\frac{a_n}{z^{n-1}}=0$

Or am I missing something?

Comment: Analytic at $|z|>1$ means it's more natural to make a power series in $\frac1z$ than in $z$ (and then the problem translates to showing that there are no $(1/z)^n$ terms for negative $n$). A power series in $z$ corresponds to the function being analytic at $0$. Edit: You still can't take a derivative of a limit, and just because two functions have the same limit doesn't mean their derivatives do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Analytic functions in $\{|z|>1\}$ don't have a power series expansion around $0$ unless they extend to the entire complex plane. Here is  a proof: let $g(z)=f(\frac 1 z)$ for $0<|z|<1$. Then $g$ is analytic and $g(z)\to L$ as $z \to 0$. Hence $g$ extends to an analytic function on the unit disk. It follows that $z^{2}g'(z)\to 0$ as $z \to 0$. In terms of $f$ this gives $f'(z)\to 0$ as $|z| \to \infty$. which gives what you want.

Comment: And even the stronger conclusion that $f'(z)=O(1/|z|^2)$ when $|z|\to\infty$.

Comment: So basically what we have done was to create an entire function $g(z)=\begin{cases}
f(z), |z|>1\\
f(\frac{1}{z}), |z|\leq 1\end{cases}$?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2094408/the-analytic-function-at-infinity#2094416