# If a function is analytic at infinity, then its derivative tends to zero.

Tags: complex-analysis

A complex function $f$ is called analytic at infinity if the function $g$ defined by $g(z) = f(1/z)$ is analytic at $0$. Prove that the limit of $f'(z)$ as z goes to infinity is $0$.

Can we solve this without knowing that the derivative of $g$ is continuous in a neighborhood of $0$? This is obviously always true because $g$ is analytic at $0$ but this exercise appears early in the book, where the continuity of the derivative hasn't yet been proven.

We obviously have $f'(z) = -(1/z^2)g'(1/z)$ for large values of z and even though $1/z^2$ tends to $0$ and $g'(0)$ exists, I do not know how to conclude that $f'(z)$ tends to $0$.

This question has already been answered in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2094408/the-analytic-function-at-infinity) thread **using** the continuity of $g'$. Therefore I do not think this is a duplicate.

Comment: Try with $z=Re^{i\theta}$? Let $R\to\infty$. You may also use $|z|=R$.

Comment: @MikaelHelin I am sorry but I do not understand what you suggest I should do. How does a change of coordinates help? Can you elaborate a little?